# Can't hold left button on touchpad and drag in 12.04 and no right click

Tags: 12.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, drag-and-drop

After updating to 12.04, I cannot use the mouse buttons.  I have a work around to be able to drag with the touchpad alone, also to use the touchpad for right click.  I would however like to use the actual buttons to drag and drop and actually right click.  I have an Acer Aspire S3 series laptop. Does anyone know why this may be happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is the fix for right click on a touchpad with no buttons i.e. a clickpad!!

create a folder:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

the create a file called 51.synaptics.conf

open gedit in root and save the file in the above folder with the following text in the file:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
MatchDriver "synaptics"
Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

log out and then log back in again and you will have right click

if you do not have a clickpad and have actual buttons see what your touchpad is capable off:

```
xinput -list (to find the name of your touchpad)
```

then:

```
xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" | grep Capabilities
```

you should see some output like this:

```
Synaptics Capabillities (295):  1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

the numbers mean the following:

```
(1) device has a physical left button
(0) device does not have a physical middle button
(0) device does not have a physical right button
(1) device does support two-finger detection
(1) device does support three-finger detection
(1) device can configure vertical resolution
(1) device can configure horizontal resolution
```

if I was you I would take a look at the my comment and follow the link, this should help solve your problem.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

Comment: I do have hard buttons.  when I pull up the xinput, the device is actually "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" and it pulls up as 1,0,1,1,1,1,1.  When I click the right button, it gives the same effect as a left click.

Comment: if you have an acer aspire S3 then you have what is called in linux terms as a clickpad. see if clickpad is enabled by using the "synclient -l" command. if its set to Clickpad = 0, then it is not recognising that you have a clickpad. Change this by issuing the following command: synclient Clickpad=1. to make it permanent you can add the command to the startup applications.

Comment: outside of the above you could try the following: sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps. then to make it permanent: sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/options then add options psmouse proto=imps. once you have done this save the file and then issue the following command: sudo update-grub: http://www.linlap.com/wiki/acer+aspire+s3

Comment: Note: i would always recommend using man synaptics and synclient to configure your touchpad as you have more flexibility for control and adjutsments.

Answer (score 3):

If your touchpad is not recognised as a clickpad [linux term for a touchpad with soft button areas] you can use the following `51.synaptics.conf` file:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
MatchDriver "synaptics"
Option "ClickPad"         "true"
Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
Option "SoftButtonAreas"  "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Comment: This finally worked for me!