# two finger scroll gone after changing click functionality

Tags: scrolling

So my touchpad click functionality did not work properly. It was somewhat (it's still acting a little funny) fixed now by another solution I found here [Can't hold left button on touchpad and drag in 12.04 and no right click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151194/cant-hold-left-button-on-touchpad-and-drag-in-12-04-and-no-right-click)

However, after this fix, suddenly the two finger scrolling option is gone which wás there before. Does anyone have an idea why this is and how I can bring it back?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?
In short, what I did is change the settings so that click-drag was possible. After this change suddenly the two finger scroll and side scroll options are gone. It's just not there anymore.