# Synaptics ClickPad jumping on selection

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad, synaptics

I just got Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my new ThinkPad E460 and it happens to have one of those "clickpads" where the buttons are hidden under the touchpad (like apple computers).

The problem is when I drag and drop, I click and hold the left button (underneath the touchpad) and move another finger on the pad. But ubuntu seems to be confused and can't figure out which of the two fingers is supposed to "drag" and so the mouse jumps around.

The issue was reported 2 years ago in this post: [Lenovo synaptics clickpad dead zones (click and drag issues)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582247/lenovo-synaptics-clickpad-dead-zones-click-and-drag-issues)
But none of the solutions proposed satisfy me: changing AreaBottomEdge does not fix the issue, and the Soft Button Area is already defined, as my touchpad was correctly recognised as a clickpad by Ubuntu,

Here are the options I have on xinput:

```
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad':
Device Enabled (138):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (140): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (261): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (262):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (263):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (264):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (265):  614, 3481, 307, 1740
Synaptics Finger (266): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (267):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (268):   201
Synaptics Tap Durations (269):  180, 100, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (270):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (271):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (272):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (273):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (274): -91, -91
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (275): 1, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (276):   1, 0
Synaptics Move Speed (277): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.043687, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (278):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (279):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (280):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (281): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
Synaptics Click Action (282):   1, 3, 2
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (283): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (284):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (285): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (286):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (287): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (288):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (289): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (290):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (291): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (292):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (293):  0
Synaptics Gestures (294):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (295):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (296): 38, 42
Synaptics Area (297):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (298):  2047, 0, 1678, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (299): 22, 22
Device Product ID (256):    2, 8
Device Node (257):  "/dev/input/event6"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried Ubuntu 16.10, with the same result: it still jumps around when drag and dropping.

EDIT2: I have also tried Fedora. In Fedora it works properly! But... I really like Ubuntu much better (I'm used to apt-get etc...) So I would rather use Ubuntu. Nonetheless, what configuration files/package version should I look inside Fedora to figure which might be causing the problem in Ubuntu?

EDIT3: I checked, and Fedora seems to have xserver-xorg-synaptics version 1.9.0 instead of 1.8. Could this be the difference. I don't seem to able to find a way to install version 1.9.0 of this package in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it didn't quite work... It depends on xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04, which in turn made me remove a bunch of packages. After reboot my keyboard did not work anymore, and I loged in in a guest session (could not type a password) and tried the mouse but it still jumps around. I am now reinstalling the system (I had nothing on it anyway) to get my keyboard back. Any other suggestion? Thanks again

Comment: Wow, sorry for the hassle. I don't have any more ideas, and if I did, I don't think I'd want to risk causing a problem like that again. ;)

Comment: Oh, it turns out that's an opt-in for xorg and kernel rolling update. I hope nobody else did that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution! The always trusted Debian saved me. I leave it here for people with the same trouble.

I added the repositories from Debian Sid (I believe the same version fo packages is in Debian Stretch):

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
```

to the /etc/apt/sources.list

Then obviously

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then I went on synaptic and got rid of the following packages:

```
Removed the following packages:
ubuntu-desktop
xorg
xserver-common
xserver-xorg
xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-input-all
xserver-xorg-input-evdev
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
xserver-xorg-input-wacom
xserver-xorg-video-all
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
xserver-xorg-video-ati
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
xserver-xorg-video-qxl
xserver-xorg-video-radeon
xserver-xorg-video-vesa
xserver-xorg-video-vmware
```

Then installed, with the latest version which is the one coming from Debian:

```
Upgraded the following packages:
libgcrypt20 (1.6.5-2ubuntu0.2) to 1.7.6-1
libinput10 (1.2.3-1ubuntu1) to 1.6.0-1
libwacom-bin (0.18-1) to 0.22-1
libwacom-common (0.18-1) to 0.22-1
libwacom2 (0.18-1) to 0.22-1

Installed the following packages:
libinput-bin (1.6.0-1)
libxcb-util0 (0.3.8-3)
libxfont2 (1:2.0.1-3)
xfonts-100dpi (1:1.0.4+nmu1)
xfonts-75dpi (1:1.0.4+nmu1)
xorg (1:7.7+18)
xserver-xorg (1:7.7+18)
xserver-xorg-core (2:1.19.1-4)
xserver-xorg-input-all (1:7.7+18)
xserver-xorg-input-libinput (0.23.0-2)
xserver-xorg-input-synaptics (1.9.0-1+b1)
xserver-xorg-video-all (1:7.7+18)
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu (1.2.0-1+b1)
xserver-xorg-video-ati (1:7.8.0-1+b1)
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev (1:0.4.4-1+b5)
xserver-xorg-video-intel (2:2.99.917+git20161206-1)
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (1:1.0.13-1+b1)
xserver-xorg-video-qxl (0.1.4+20161126git4d7160c-1)
xserver-xorg-video-radeon (1:7.8.0-1+b1)
xserver-xorg-video-vesa (1:2.3.4-1+b2)
xserver-xorg-video-vmware (1:13.2.1-1+b1)
```

And finally added the remaining packages:

```
Installed the following packages:
ubuntu-desktop (1.361)
xserver-xorg-input-evdev (1:2.10.5-1)
```

There are two packages that were removed and I could not substitute with Debian versions: `xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse` and `xserver-xorg-input-wacom`. But I personally don't need them since my laptop is not a Wacom tablet and I don't intend to use VMWare (I like VirtualBox better).

I hope it helps someone

---

Edit: Of course, this goes without saying, disable the Debian repositories after doing this... I am using heir repos to fix a bug, not for my everyday life. If I wanted to have the headaches that Sid gave me 10 years ago I would have installed Debian Sid...

Comment: I'm glad this helped you, but in practice, you should *never* mix Debian and Ubuntu packages. See here: http://askubuntu.com/a/116266/457562

Comment: There does not seem to be a better solution though! The packages are stable: Fedora 25 carries those same versions and they are in Debian Sid, but also in Debian Testing/Stretch. If Ubuntu starts to be a bit faster on releasing packages, then there would be no problem.  The point is this is a solution to the problem. If people are naive enough to use Debian repos in Ubuntu for everyday use, that's their problem. I used it for a fix and then disabled it. And I changed the versions of all xorg so the whole suite matches versions. I'm confident this is fine.  I edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: Perhaps you should file a bug in the launchpad page about how it should be updated.